# What is "38 years too gay" supposed to mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, semantics

Pete Buttigieg, Hosting ‘Jimmy Kimmel Live,’ Jokes About Presidential Bid: “Turns Out I Was About 40 Years Too Young And 38 Years Too Gay”

He also made several jokes about his young age, and the notion that he had too little experience for the White House.“Running for president was an amazing experience,” he said. “The support my campaign got was unbelievable and I really thought we had a shot.Turns out I was about 40 years too young and 38 years too gay.”

I’ve noticed that in English noun can sometimes function as an adverbial, for example "Ryan is book smart."(Michael Scott’s line in The Office).And I think it’s the same case here."about 40 years too young" means about 40 years old seems a bit young for running for POTUS.However I’m not quite sure about "38 years too gay".Is it some kind of sarcasm?"38 years" doesn’t function as an adverbial here, it’s just the fact that he’s 38 years old and gay which may not found to be favorable by some of voters due to homophobia.Am I right?

Comment: I think the _40 years too young_ is a reference to the age gap to the other (much older) candidates.

Comment: For the record, he's 38 years old.  Trump is 73, Biden 77, Sanders 78.

Comment: Well yes, he's 38 and he's gay, but put that together and here's been gay for 38 years, and that is a hindrance to being elected because of some voters' views. The A years too B, X years too Y parallel wording is a kind of standard joke formula.

Comment: It's a joke. Don't try to analyse it.